# Cannot Find File System.IO.File.Exists();

Tags: c#

I have file on my desktop named `"Employees.xlsx"`. When I try to find it it says that does not exists. What did I missed ?

```
bool a = System.IO.File.Exists(@"‪‪‪‪C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Employees.xlsx"); //returns false instead of true
```

Comment: Is it really in that folder when you look there using windows explorer? On desktop could mean also default desktop folder.

Comment: Your code is correct. Are you sure there's no typo? Try to open Excel, then bring the open file dialog and paste the path inside.

Comment: Also there is a small chance that your app does not have read permission to the file while executing in different security context.

Comment: I created new project and it is working now ? What is wrong with the current ?

Comment: Try to restart VS and run the old project.

Comment: After the restart the old project is working too. What the hell is happening ?

Comment: Do not worry, be happy!

Comment: When I right click and copy the path it is not working ? The windows is brand new. Is it some configurations which i should make ?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use full path as string, use the built-in helper functions:

```
System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Employees.xlsx");
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be a typo? try right clicking the file with <kbd>Shift</kbd>  and select "Copy as path". then <kbd>Paste</kbd> it into  `Visual Studio`.

Comment: I did it but the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tested 'Lucas Trzesniewski's comment?
Make 'OpenFileDialog' instance and open excel file using it. 
And check exists method.

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
openFileDialog.ShowDialog();

bool result = System.IO.File.Exists(openFileDialog.FileName);
```

If result is true, then check difference.